# Thoughts on Mersenne numbers

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

Mersenne numbers are numbers of the form $2^n-1$. Let us use the standard symbol $M_n$ for them.

I am interested here in opinions about methods for obtaining the answers of these two questions:

> Problem 1: Are there infinitely many composite numbers $M_n$ when $n$ is prime number?
>
> Problem 2: Are there infinitely many prime numbers $M_n$ when $n$ is prime number?

I am aware that there are some theorems which give us some information about Mersenne numbers and that there is Lucas-Lehmer test which gives necessary and sufficient condition for $M_p$ to be a prime number but still I do not understand why after relatively long period of time since two above stated problems are formulated we still do not have answers to them?

I have some thoughts which I would like to share with you. First, the problem 2 is, in my opinion, still not settled because we still do not know enough about prime numbers in general, regardless of the form which describes them (here the form which describes them is $2^n-1$). Second, I think the problem 1 is still not settled because we still do not have specialized methods of factorization which are applicable for numbers which appear in some particular form. And third, I think that problem 2 is not settled because we do not have efficient enough tests for primality, which is, in some way, a consequence of the fact that we still do not know enough about prime numbers in general.

It could be that my thoughts about these 2 problems are not precise enough or that are not the true reasons why the above two problems are still not settled so i would like to hear your opinions about these two problems stated above and about the reasons that are, in your opinion, the reasons that describe why the problems are still not settled and what kind of methods should or/and could be used to settle them finally?

Comment: "I do not understand why after relatively long period of time [...] we still do not have answers to them?" I suspect the answer to this is simply that these problems are _extremely hard_.

Comment: To understand why we do not have answers "after relatively long period of time" is the first step into prime number theory. Do you know for how long the Goldbach conjecture is open now ?

Comment: It is hard to imagine that the number of COMPOSITE $M_n$ , $n$ a prime, is finite. This would mean, that $M_n$ is always prime for a prime $n$ sufficiently large. Of course, such intuitions are no proof ...

Comment: @Peter:  That only holds when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  For example, $p = 5$ is a Sophie Germain prime, but $2^5-1 = 31$ is prime, and in particular not divisible by 11.  (It's believed but not known that infinitely many such primes exist.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I noticed it at night, but did not go online anymore ...